# Enter multiple documents to same the same index in elastic search

Tags: java, elasticsearch, kibana

I'm new to elasticsearch, what I want to achieve is to insert multiple documents, that is, values to the same id in the index. Is it possible? When I try it the documents are getting updated. Let me know if it's possible ,thanks.

Comment: Can you expand a little bit more on your use case? Maybe show some example.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is store different and multiple tagnames for a single employee. For ex, if employee id is 001 then I expect to store different tagnames like "salary_slip", "tax_slip", etc for employee id 001. Finally I want it to look like : 001: "salary_slip", "tax_slip".

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [bulk-API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html) to store multiple documents at once, but you can not store different documents with the same ID. Maybe you can achieve what you need by using the [versioning feature](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html).

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing sounds like the [Array Datatype](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/array.html).  Per the ES documentation, you can put an array of strings into one field like so:

```
PUT my_index/_doc/1
{
  "message": "some arrays in this document...",
  "tags":  [ "elasticsearch", "wow" ], 
  "lists": [ 
    {
      "name": "prog_list",
      "description": "programming list"
    },
    {
      "name": "cool_list",
      "description": "cool stuff list"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: is it possible to append the new names to that list? because in my case, it was getting updated.

Comment: Yes, whenever you update the tags in document, you can just send the new set of values.  For example, if you want to append `"such"` to the tags, you just send `["elasticsearch", "wow", "such"]`, along with the rest of the fields.

Comment: Thanks for the response, and in that case, I need to retain the old values and append the new value to it and then send the tag. Is this what you're saying? If that's the case, then, wouldn't become a lengthy process where I need to fetch all the previous values and insert? I mean update

Comment: If you have the ID of the document(s) to update, you can issue partial updates on the tags: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/partial-updates.html